# Downloading image from Url in java.Server returned HTTP response code: 403 error. How can I get the connection to work?

Tags: java, opencv, url

I am trying to downloada picture from a certain url, but cant do so because I somehow have to give the right userclient to the website.I am sure the problem is that I cant give the user client while using the Url class, because  the page can be accesed via browser. I tried using proxy and Urlconnection but couldnt get it  to work. Please share your toughts on the matter!

My code is the following:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;

public class KepLetolto {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        File file = new File("tempjpeg");
         SocketAddress address = new java.net.InetSocketAddress("xyz.com", 8080);

         // Create an HTTP Proxy using the above SocketAddress.
         Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, address);


        URL url_kep =new URL("http://www.theouthousers.com/images/templates/thumbnails/128058/bayfinger_size3.png");

        ImageIO.write(ImageIO.read(url_kep), "jpeg", file);

        Mat uj = Highgui.imread("temp.jpeg" ,Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);  

    }

}
```

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: The question is that, how can I get rid of the error? Btw can I edit the question title?

Comment: Yes, you can edit the entire question, including the title and the tags. While you're at it, add information such as why you think you need to do something with the user client and what did you try to do about it and where it failed.

Comment: I have edited it. The main problem is that I dont know a class or tool for this.

Comment: Thank you, this works for me. Can you make this an answer, it can help out poeple in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `ImageIO.read(URL)`, which limits you to the default behavior of the URL's underlying `URLConnection`, use `ImageIO.read(InputStream)`.

This allows you to use any HTTP client library - including the basic [`HttpURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), which you can get from `(HttpURLConnection)url_kep.openConnection()`. Using that, you can set headers such as `User-Agent`, if that's the header required by the site, or other headers such as `Referer` which are sometimes used to prevent deep-linking.

Once you set up all the headers and any other request options, you can get an `InputStream` from the client object, and pass that to `ImageIO`.

Answer (score 0):

This Solution Worked For Me:

```
URLConnection openConnection = new URL("YOUR_IMAGE_URL").openConnection();
openConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "YOUR USER AGENT");
InputStream is = openConnection.getInputStream();
BufferedImage saveImage = ImageIO.read(is);
ImageIO.write(saveImage, "png", new File("PATH\\TO\\IMAGE\\FILE.PNG"));
```

Comment: Could you provide more of an explanation to your answer?